# Error GW100 encountered when restricting transport modes to walk-only in HERE's Public Transit API

Tags: python, rest, here-api

I am currently a user of HERE's Public Transit APIs, implemented using REST on Python 3.7.

My goal is to obtain walking-only routes between two locations on my school campus. To do so, I have tried including the `"modes"` parameter whose value is the string `"walk"`, along with other parameters required by the API.

However, I am always met with the GW100 error code, accompanied by the text "Invalid request: Request is not valid under any of the given schemas".

The main bit of code which I used is as follows, which is sufficient to reproduce the error:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

current_location = "1.298680,103.771922"
destination_coords = "1.29437,103.78436"
apiKey = "insert API Key"

modes = "walk"

routing_base_url = "https://transit.ls.hereapi.com/v3/route.json"

time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond = 0)
time = time.isoformat()

maximum = 1
graph = 1
maneuvers = 1

routing_params = {"apiKey": apiKey, "dep": current_location, "arr": destination_coords, "time": time, "max": maximum, "graph": graph, "maneuvers": maneuvers,"modes": modes}

raw_data = requests.get(url = routing_base_url, params = routing_params)
data = raw_data.json()

print(data)
```

Running the code in Python yields the following error message:

```
{'Res': {'serviceUrl': 'https://transit.ls.hereapi.com/transit/v3/route.json', 'Message': {'code': 'GW100', 'level': 'E', 'text': 'Invalid request: Request is not valid under any of the given schemas'}}}
```

The error seems to stem from the `"modes"` parameter. I have checked the Public Transit API guide to ensure `"modes"` is of the correct type and format: a string containing the names of the required transport modes. The list of all parameters accepted by the API are listed [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/resource-routing.html), while the list of transport modes for `"modes"` are listed [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/key-concepts-transit-codes.html).

Removing it entirely from the `routing_params` dictionary or setting its value to be an empty string `""` leads to a route being generated by the API. However the route will use forms of transport besides walking, which is what I don't want.

What seems to be the problem here? `"modes"` is already of the correct type and format, but the error seems to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

We will ask the team to correct it on portal.

Looks like correct parameter is `mode = "walk"`. Kindly update this in your code and it should work.